# Trouble with importing ListView

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-import, django-class-based-views

I'm using `python 3.7` and `django 2.1`. Trying to create a class based view, and first have to import it in my views.py. So I put:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
```

which is what the tutorial said to do. When I run the server, I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Listview' from 'django.views.generic
```

I tried it with

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
```

but that didn't work either.

Anyone have any ideas? Pretty new to coding, let me know if there's a better way to ask the question as well. I was as specific as I could be.

Comment: `from django.views.generic.list import ListView`

Comment: Do you realize that your  two attempts are trying to import two different names -- `Listview` and `ListView`?

Comment: have you installed django-rest-framework

Comment: There is nothing called `Listview` in Django, It is `ListView` , This is correct `from django.views.generic import ListView`

Comment: @JohnGordon, I inputed it incorrectly above, but correctly in my text editor. I've edited the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

**`Example from` [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)**

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views.generic.list import ListView     # <-- Working

from articles.models import Article

class ArticleListView(ListView):

    model = Article
    paginate_by = 100  # if pagination is desired

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        return context
```